# Alternative to MongoDB maximum index key length?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to add search capability to my application, in which I'm using MongoDB (2.6.6), Mongoose (3.8.8) and ExpressJs (4.7.2).

I'm using the following method to make some fields of my collection indexable.

```
UserSchema.index({
  field1: 'text',
  field2: 'text',
  field3: 'text',
  field4: 'text',
  field5: 'text',
  field6: 'text'
});
```

But it turns out that this index does have a maximum length, according to [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/).
When I have only 5 fields, the search works perfectly, but when I add the 6th one, it seems like I reach the maximum length. And the index is not created.

I'm using something like this for the search:

```
User.find({ $text: { $search: 'foo' }})
```

And I use this to check the indexes:

```
db.users.getIndexes()
```

So what would be the best way to solve this ? Is there any alternative ways of doing this search ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are indexing and finding that way, unless I have missed something.

For a compound index like what you are doing, you can have up to 31 fields as stated here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

With Mongoose, you are supposed to index like so:

`var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    last_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      index: true
    },
    accessToken: {
      type: String,
      index: true
    },
    created: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
      index: true
    },
    provider: {
      type: String,
      index: true
    }
});`

`userSchema.index({email: 1, first_name: 1, last_name: 1, accessToken: 1, created: -1, provider: 1}) //1 or -1 depending on how to sort your index`

Lastly to Search, simply do:

`User.find({email: 'rahat@me.com'}, function(err, data) ...)`

OR multiple fields:

`User.findOne({first_name: 'Rahat', last_name: 'Mahbub'}, function(err, data) ...)`

Reference: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/